# How do I see modal by clicking image in react??(instagram clone coding)

Tags: reactjs, antd, simplemodal

```
import { Modal } from "antd";

function Profile(){

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

return(

  <>
    {myposts.map((mypost, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <img
              key={index}
              className="item"
              onClick={() => {
                setVisible(true);
              }}
              src={`http://localhost:5000/uploads/${mypost.photo}`}
            />
            {visible && (
              <Modal
                title="Basic Modal"
                visible={visible}
                onOk={setVisible(false)}
                onCancel={setVisible(false)}
              >
                <p>Some contents...</p>
                <p>Some contents...</p>
                <p>Some contents...</p>
              </Modal>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
   )}
```

This is the summery of my code. I think when I click image, it should makes modal. But, It doesn't work anything. I don't know which part is wrong. (Modal part has some strange content now. I'll change this part after seeing modal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the modal outside the mypost map, maybe this is why the modal won't show up. You may need another state for the src path of the selected image.

```
import { Modal } from "antd";

function Profile() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [selectedImgSrc, setSelectedImgSrc] = useState("");

  const imgClick = (imgSrc) => {
    setSelectedImgSrc(imgSrc);
    setVisible(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {myposts.map((mypost, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <img
              key={index}
              className="item"
              onClick={() => {
                imgClick(`http://localhost:5000/uploads/${mypost.photo}`);
              }}
              src={`http://localhost:5000/uploads/${mypost.photo}`}
            />
          </>
        );
      })}

      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={visible}
        onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
        onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
      >
        <img src={selectedImgSrc} />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I completely solve my problem with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the problem is here in your code.

```html
  <Modal
    title="Basic Modal"
    visible={visible}
    onOk={setVisible(false)}
    onCancel={setVisible(false)}
  >
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
  </Modal>
```

```
onOk={setVisible(false)}
onCancel={setVisible(false)}
```

The problem is these lines.
When you click an image it opens your modal, but when the modal being to render, these lines are setting visible state as `false`. So the modal will be deleted from DOM soon.
That's why you can not see your modal on clicking an image.

Please try with this.

```
onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
```

You should pass a function for onOk and onCancel props.